# Replace stock clipboard on Android

Tags: android, clipboard, translate

Os there a way to replace the system clipboard in Android? I'd like to build a custom open source clipboard that once a user copies some text then this text should be translated by the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't **replace** the Android clipboard, because this is part of the system. But what you can do is make a **service** implementing an `OnPrimaryClipChangedListener()`

That way you'll be able to intercept copied text, and translate it.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html for more information on this